# How to use argmax on a numpy array

Tags: python, machine-learning, numpy-ndarray

I'm using Keras deep learning in Python.
I have a numpy array that has this shape: [5, 30, 30, 30, 65]
I want to perform an argmax along the 5th dimension (65), setting the index of the highest value in each 5th array to 1 and all others to 0. For context, the array is being outputted by a generator model, and I'm using the last dimension of length 65 as a one-hot encoding.
How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

To perform the `argmax` operation on the 5th dimension, you can specify the `axis` parameter using 0-based counting.

Therefore, to get the `argmax` for the 5th dimension you would use: 
`idx = np.argmax(arr, axis=4)[0, 0, 0, 0]`

Then, to covert the 5th dimension array to a one-hot encoding, you can set that array to an `np.zeros` array and then updated the value at `idx` (from above) to be 1 as follows:

```py
arr[a, b, c, d] = np.zeros((65,))
arr[a, b, c, d, idx] = 1
```

where `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are abritrary indices along the 1st through 4th dimensions.